# numpy elementwise comparison with overloaded operator

Tags: python, numpy, operator-overloading

I have two numpy arrays containing objects with an overloaded comparison operator that returns another object, instead of True or False.  How can I create an array containing the results of the individual comparisons.  I would like result to be an array of objects like in the following

```
lhs = ... # np.array of objects with __le__ overloaded
rhs = ... # another np.array
result = np.array([l <= r for l, r in izip(lhs, rhs)])
```

but `lhs <= rhs` gives me an array of bools.
Is there a way to get to the `result` to be the array of the results of the `__le__` method calls without writing a python loop?

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.less_equal.html#numpy.less_equal) for `np.less_equal` (and the other comparison functions) says it returns "the truth value" of the comparison, so it may not be possible to do this without manually iterating over the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Numpy's Github page](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/4cbced22a8306d7214a4e18d12e651c034143922/doc/source/reference/arrays.ndarray.rst) on `ndarray` states that the comparison operators are equivalent to the *ufunc* forms in Numpy. Therefore `lhs <= rhs` is equivalent to `np.less_equal(lhs, rhs)`

From the output of `np.info(np.less_equal)`

```
 Returns
 ------- out : bool or ndarray of bool
   Array of bools, or a single bool if `x1` and `x2` are scalars.
```

To get around this you can use:

```
import operator
result = np.vectorize(operator.le)(lhs, rhs)
```

The `np.vectorize` will allow you to use Numpy's broadcasting in the comparisons too. It will use your objects comparison and will return a numpy array of the results of those comparisons in the same form as your list comprehension.

Comment: The `__le__` function that we're not allowed to see is operating in a plain old Python list comprehension not a numpy context. Therefore, np.less_equal is not called.

Comment: @msw `lhs <= rhs` is what the OP wanted to use, which calls `np.less_than`, I'm stating why it returns bool instead of the results of the comparisons as he expected.